# Java hashCode() equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, oop, hash

Java have a method inside every class called hashCode() witch returns a number. Is there any method to obtain this is c++? I tried std::hash<> from stl but it doesn't work for classes, only primitive types.
ex:

```
Person p;
hash<Person> hs;
cout<<hs(p); // if i replace Person with `int, vector<bool> etc` it works
```

Comment: That is correct. You must implement `std::hash` for your classes by yourself. You will also do yourself a favor if you completely forget everything you know about Java when trying to learn C++. Despite very similar syntax, C++ is fundamentally different from Java in many ways, and C++ objects are fundamentally different from Java objects. If you keep trying to compare C++ with Java, you will only end up confusing yourself, at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you've no default hash code method.
The reason why std::hash works is that std::hash has a defined implementation for that type.
To define your hash implementation you could lookup this site: https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

General notice:
I highly recommend you to get away with your java thoughts since Java and C++ are two totally different languages with different concepts. My recommendation would be to start learning from scratch except that you've already the knowledge about how to solve problems and how to write code. (That's at least what I did)

Comment: But what if i have a template?